# GORM Gotchas Part 2 by Peter Ledbrook

Tags: grails

I am trying to understand the meaning of this phrase in the [GORM Gotchas Part 2](http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/):

> The advantage of this syntax is that you can define multiple cascading
>   relationships.

Does this mean multiple cascading relationships between Location and domain classes other than Author as well as Author or does it mean transitive (chaining) cascading relationships like between Location and Author and then Author and some other domain class? Can anyone provide an example of the syntax of these multiple cascading relationships? I think that will make it clearer. Thank you.

Comment: Have you asked Peter what he meant by that?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Yes, I did on May 19th. See here: https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/36065.page but I didn't get a reply yet.

Comment: You would probably have better luck contacting him directly rather than involving Manning.  His web site at http://www.cacoethes.co.uk suggests using p.ledbrook@cacoethes.co.uk.

Comment: the whole section there (please quote enough context next time so the question remains valid even if the blog site there decides to change urls) is about the two ways one can write `belongsTo`.  either pass a class or a map. the sentece is just about the advantage of using  the map (which allows more than one relation)

Comment: @cfrick so multiple relationships can't be done with class names alone, a map must be used?

Answer (score 0):

I will provide an example from our current application: We have `User`s and `Home`s. A home has many residents (instances of `User`) which can live in multiple `Home`s.

A user can now register a `WebHook` for any events happening on the home.
If the user gets deleted (his account is removed), we want to remove all web hooks, registered by this user.
If a home gets deleted the users remain, but all web hooks of this home should be removed (since there will not be any more events happening for the deleted home).

So the class `WebHook` would look like this:

```
class WebHook {
    String url

    static belongsTo = [home: Home, registrator: User]
}
```

The `belongsTo` relation in this case is a map, which adds `home` and `registrator` as properties on the `WebHook` class. If you do not need the references but just want to have the cascading behavior, you can also use a list and define the `belongsTo` relation like this:

```
static belongsTo = [Home, User]
```

Both ways guarantee that the web hook gets deleted when either the home or the user associated with it get deleted.